# Cannot open powercfg.cpl

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, control-panel, powercfg

I cannot open `powercfg.cpl`

When i was opening control panel, windows explorer stopped working and shows "windows explorer is restarting". but control panel is not opening. I went to windows `directory>>system32` and checked for powercfg.cpl file it was not working.

Any idea about how I can fix this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: create a crashdump and upload it: http://pastebin.com/HAh45FFJ

Comment: Did you try in Safe Mode? System restore?

Comment: This problem surfaces after a reboot?

Comment: @CharlieRB I tried Safe Mode, System restore is not possible as I don't know when the problem started.

Comment: @Ramhound the problem occurs when I try to open control panel.

Comment: create the dump and share it. Everything else else pure speculation.

Comment: I know it occurs when you open the control panel.  But does the problem happen when you reboot or boot into safe mode?

Comment: No, it doesn't happen on boot.

Comment: looks like you don't want help. Why do you ask here if you don't provide the required data to troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do a scan [**`sfc /scannow`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491008.aspx) to check the integrity of system files.

The `sfc /scannow` command scans all protected system files and replaces incorrect versions with correct Microsoft versions.

Good luck.